# One string keeps two names after reading from file

Tags: c#, string, csv, io

In the method:  public static void ReadBookData(string file, Library[] library)   where I read the first line of a .csv file and add one city to library[0] (I am aware that this is an array but I tried getting atleast one city there because when reading from .csv file it pushes all names into one)

```
 line = reader.ReadLine();                 
    if (line != null)                  
    {               
       town = line;                                                                                                                                           
    }

library[0] = new Library(town);
```

And when I try to `Console.WriteLine(library[0].Town);` I get: Copenhagen (new line) Berlin

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace P3
{
    class Book
    {
        public string ISBN { get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public string AuthorName { get; set; } 
        public string AuthorSurname { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; } 
        public string Publisher { get; set; }
        public int PublishYear { get; set; }
        public string Pages { get; set; }      

        public Book(string isbn, string name, string authorName, string authorSurname, string type, string publisher, int publishYear, string pages)
        {
            ISBN = isbn;
            Name = name;
            AuthorName = authorName;
            AuthorSurname = authorSurname;
            Type = type;
            Publisher = publisher;
            PublishYear = publishYear;
            Pages = pages;
        }
    }

    class BooksContainer
    {
        public Book[] Books { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; private set; }

        public BooksContainer(int size)
        {
            Books = new Book[size];
        }
        public void AddBook(Book book)
        {
            Books[Count] = book;
            Count++;
        }
        public Book GetBook(int index)
        {
            return Books[index];
        }
    }

    class Library
    {
        public const int MaxNumberOfBooks = 100;

        public string Town { get; set; }
        public BooksContainer Books { get; private set; }

        public Library( string town)
        {
            Town = town;
        } 
      }

    class Program
    {   
        public static void ReadBookData(string file, Library[] library)   
        {
            BooksContainer books = new BooksContainer(20);
            string town = null;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@file))
            {

                string line = null;
                line = reader.ReadLine();          
                if (line != null)
                {
                    town = line;                                                                                                                                           
                }
                library[0] = new Library(town);

                    while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
                    {
                        string[] values = line.Split(';');
                        string isbn = values[0];  
                        string name = values[1];  
                        string authorName = values[2]; 
                        string authorSurname = values[3]; 
                       string type = values[4];  
                        string publisher = values[5]; 
                        int publishYear = Int32.Parse(values[6]);  
                        string pages = values[7];     
                        Book book = new Book(isbn, name, authorName, authorSurname, type, publisher, publishYear, pages);
                    }

            }
            Console.WriteLine(library[0].Town);

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                
            Library[] library = new Library[10];
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"*.csv");

            foreach (string path in filePaths)
            {
                ReadBookData(path, library);
            }                                                         
        }
    }
}
```

.csv files

First

```
 - Copenhagen
 - 9785415023455;Psichoanalizes ivadas;Sigmund Freud;Knyga;Vaga;2014;462;
 - 9786098088106;Mokslas ir tikejimas: naujasis ivadas;John F. Haught;Knyga;Vox altera;2014;174;
```

Second .csv file

```
 - Berlin

 - 9786094575143;Architekturologijos istorijos ivadas;Edita
   Riaubiene;Knyga;Technika;2013;103;

 - 9786099540672;Modernizmas: ivadas;Chris Rodrigues,Chris
   Garratt;Knyga;Modernaus meno centras;2013;176;
```

Comment: `Books[]` in `BookContainer` should be private.

Comment: It looks to me like you're calling `ReadBookData()` twice, once for the first CSV file and then for the second one. Thus, it is printing two city names and that's the output you are seeing.